# InfoPath 2013 Getting current user details error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, infopath, infopath-data-connections

I have SharePoint server 2013 and a custom list I want to get current user details in InfoPaht form 2013

I followed post from: https://spvee.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/auto-populate-user-information-in-infopath-with-claims-based-authentication-part-1-of-3/

but when I preview my form I get bellow error:

```
The SOAP response indicates that an error occurred on the server:

Server was unable to process request. ---> Attempted to perform an  unauthorized operation.
```

when I open the form in browser I get bellow error:

```
 An error occurred while trying to connect to a Web service.


 An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server. 

Log ID:5566


 Correlation ID:b620719d-1f52-d035-bad8-74b03605738f

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
An error occurred while trying to connect to a Web service.


An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server. 

Log ID:5566


Correlation ID:b620719d-1f52-d035-bad8-74b03605738f
```

I am the site collection administrator I have full access to site but I don't know why I get this error.

Comment: does it work in the InfoPath client outside of the browser?

Comment: I have already mentioned that in my question in form preview i get bellow error: The SOAP response indicates that an error occurred on the server:

Server was unable to process request. ---> Attempted to perform an  unauthorized operation.

Comment: What are your data connections point to? Any sql servers or web services?

Answer (score 0):

At first try with enabling Administrator-Approved form template option.

If not worked, follow this link:
https://talesfromitside.wordpress.com/2012/01/17/sharepoint-infopath-and-user-profile-web-service-issues/